# Adding up certain values in a Column for certain Rows USING AWK

Tags: linux, shell, awk, scripting

I want to **sum up** the values in **Column 4** for the Rows whose **Column 3** is equal to **1** using Awk for the data given below.

```
13.804 2 1 0.128 14.10683054308584
13.805 4 1 0.1 16.404063320609485
13.845 4 1 0.1 18.88784810910845
13.887 3 0 0.5 15.885403793537332
13.900 2 1 0.128 17.432392753144814
13.910 0 1 0.15 14.065390777016884
13.919 2 1 0.128 14.303367876393343
13.925 0 1 0.15 99.709674389069306
13.967 4 0 0.1 16.166182416686354
13.987 2 0 0.128 27.678527587660298
13.990 0 0 0.15 16.335622854953012
13.991 3 0 0.5 18.135064819504496
14.017 2 0 0.128 32.702333086991857
14.034 1 0 0.25 23.747057691617819
14.042 1 0 0.25 21.28645813221631
14.042 4 0 0.1 32.412778602456548
14.042 4 0 0.1 16.355373059379346
14.049 4 0 0.1 16.9107377441049
14.061 4 0 0.1 14.247305256107564
14.068 3 0 0.5 17.503919428057454
14.085 0 0 0.15 15.027892690096117
14.098 0 0 0.15 18.872227052735838
14.098 1 0 0.25 32.769497723363287
14.100 0 0 0.15 14.169509642396147
14.123 0 0 0.15 15.384714430934654
14.127 0 0 0.15 16.186777071833166
14.159 2 0 0.128 26.62600293363089
14.161 0 0 0.15 14.378881668687308
14.176 2 1 0.128 32.252258371764931
14.206 4 0 0.1 15.524216799990542
14.255 4 0 0.1 22.657759416211846
14.277 4 0 0.1 15.098140555235378
14.309 1 1 0.25 14.907511075479166
14.338 2 1 0.128 23.05330560466021
14.340 0 1 0.15 19.689321884956239
14.356 3 0 0.5 134.27562471483711
14.360 0 1 0.15 16.688768682324934
14.371 4 1 0.1 15.574474425386159
14.372 4 1 0.1 18.3483146897773
14.380 0 1 0.15 22.180348478940314
14.396 0 1 0.15 17.998478450267356
14.402 2 1 0.128 15.971205833886451
14.405 2 1 0.128 28.328755195061586
14.457 2 1 0.128 75.285563263357076
14.521 2 1 0.128 23.344965171769058
14.528 4 1 0.1 16.572185579506026
14.534 0 1 0.15 55.568075650030558
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `awk` can do that for you

```
awk '$3==1{sum += $4} END{print sum }'
```

**Test**

```
$ awk '$3==1{sum += $4} END{print sum }' file 
2.952
```